# Python to populate sql with data based on Serial number on web page

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I need to produce a database in the following format from a Python script, I already produce the data but in the wrong format, so I need to modify the code and sql to work with my local host web page

The data is from a Raspberry PI and a 1 wire temperature sensor setup

I currently have 3 sensors, each with a unique serial number, the serial numbers are shown below the database, the 3 sensors are POND, FILTER, AMBIENT

```
    var myData = "date  Pond    Filter  Ambient\n\
2019-04-01 01:29:04 13.400  22.700  32.200\n\
2019-04-01 02:29:04 18.000  29.900  37.700\n\
2019-04-01 03:29:04 13.300  29.100  39.400\n\
2019-04-01 04:29:04 15.700  28.800  38.000\n\
2019-04-01 05:29:04 14.200  28.700  32.400\n\
2019-04-01 06:29:04 18.800  27.000  37.000\n\
2019-04-01 07:29:04 17.900  26.700  32.300\n\
2019-04-01 08:29:04 11.800  26.800  38.900\n\
2019-04-01 09:29:04 19.300  26.700  38.800\n\
2019-04-01 10:29:04 11.200  20.100  38.700\n\
2019-04-01 11:29:04 18.700  21.100  30.300\n\
2019-04-01 12:29:04 11.800  21.500  35.300\n\
2019-04-01 13:29:04 13.000  24.300  36.600\n\
2019-04-01 14:29:04 16.900  27.100  36.600\n\
2019-04-01 15:29:04 11.700  24.600  38.000\n";
```

Each sensor has a unique ID and I need to give it a name to make it easy to understand

```
28-0417c45ae5ff   =   Pond
28-0417c459f5ff   =   Filter
28-0517c48e7cff   =   Ambient
```

The current Python script is sending teh data to a sql data base but the format is wrong for my new web page, so I need to change the Python and sql to log the data correctly

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import fnmatch
import time
import MySQLdb as mdb
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/Sensor_error.log',
  level=logging.DEBUG,
  format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Load the modules (not required if they are loaded at boot) 
# os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
# os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

# Function for storing readings into MySQL
def insertDB(IDs, temperature):

  try:

    con = mdb.connect('localhost',
                      'temp_insert',
                      'Insert',
                      'measurements');
    cursor = con.curssql = "INSERT INTO temperature(temperature, sensor_id)\
      VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % \
      ( temperature[i], IDs[i])
      cursor.execute(sql)
      sql = []
      con.commit()

    con.close()

  except mdb.Error, e:
    logger.error(e)

# Get readings from sensors and store them in MySQL

temperature = []
IDs = []

for filename in os.listdir("/sys/bus/w1/devices"):
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '28-*'):
    with open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/" + filename + "/w1_slave") as f_obj:
      lines = f_obj.readlines()
      if lines[0].find("YES"):
        pok = lines[1].find('=')
        temperature.append(float(lines[1][pok+1:pok+6])/1000)
        IDs.append(filename)
      else:
        logger.error("Error reading sensor with ID: %s" % (filename))

if (len(temperature)>0):
  insertDB(IDs, temperature)
```

I really need the sensor serial number to be translated to its name if possible
Any help would be appreciated, its taken me weeks to get to this stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import fnmatch
import time
import MySQLdb as mdb
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/Sensor_error.log',level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Load the modules (not required if they are loaded at boot) 
# os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
# os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

# Function for storing readings into MySQL
def insertDB(IDs, temperature):

try:

    con = mdb.connect('localhost',
                  'temp_insert',
                  'Insert',
                  'measurements');
    cursor = con.curssql = "INSERT INTO temperature(temperature, sensor_id)\
           VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % \
            ( temperature[i], IDs[i])
    cursor.execute(sql)
    sql = []
    con.commit()

    con.close()

except mdb.Error, e:
    logger.error(e)

# Get readings from sensors and store them in MySQL

temperature = []
IDs = []
sensor_switch = {'28-0417c45ae5ff':'Pond', '28-0417c459f5ff':'Filter',
               '28-0517c48e7cff':'Ambient'} # a dictionary of ids

for filename in os.listdir("/sys/bus/w1/devices"):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '28-*'):
        with open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/" + filename + "/w1_slave") as f_obj:
            lines = f_obj.readlines()
            if lines[0].find("YES"):
                pok = lines[1].find('=')
                temperature.append(float(lines[1][pok+1:pok+6])/1000)
                IDs.append(sensor_switch.get(str(filename),'key_mismatch')) 
                # use a dictionary's get method to switch content
                # filename = '28-0417c45ae5ff' is switched to 'pond'
            else:
                logger.error("Error reading sensor with ID: %s" % (filename))

if (len(temperature)>0):
    insertDB(IDs, temperature)
```